# Run script when content of a file changes

Tags: linux, bash, files, inotify

I have a file with a word that changes when you move the vm on which the file resides.

For example it says "test", but if I move the vm to another server it says "test1".

Now as soon as the vm is moved and the imput of the file changes I want to run a script

I've looked at inotify but don't really see through it :C

Comment: You could use `inotifywatch`, or see https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools .

Answer (score 0):

You can check based on file modification time :

Ex:

Find the files that are modified within 24 hours i.e) 1 day.

```
find . -mtime -1  | grep <filename> && echo "File modified" || echo "File not modified"
```

Find the files that are modified within 5 minutes

```
find . -mmin -5 | grep <filename> && echo "File modified within 5 mins" || echo "File not modified"
```

You change the value for your requirement.Hope this helps!